# A function to wrap a Div with Bootstrap row and col Divs does not affect the passed parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

The code referred by the [CodePen Link](http://codepen.io/medunes/pen/JRjmpK) is supposed to result in three ".col-md-4" divs each one centered (with offsets) in a seperate row, however, that is not as I wanted it to be.

I think I am doing wrong with parameter passing and "loosing" variable values, though couldn't figure out the mistake.

```js
var wrapWithBootstrap=function(toBeWrapped)
  {
    toBeWrapped.wrap('<div class="row"></div>');
        toBeWrapped.find('.first-div').wrap('<div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4"></div>');
         toBeWrapped.find('.second-div').wrap('<div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4"></div>');
    toBeWrapped.find('.third-div').wrap('<div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4"></div>');
  }
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var wrapperDiv=$('<div class="first-div">    This is my first div.</div>');
  wrapWithBootstrap(wrapperDiv);
  $('#main').append(wrapperDiv);
  
   var wrapperDiv=$('<div class="second-div">    This is my second div.</div>');
  wrapWithBootstrap(wrapperDiv);
  $('#main').append(wrapperDiv);
  
   var wrapperDiv=$('<div class="third-div">    This is my third div.</div>');
  wrapWithBootstrap(wrapperDiv);
  $('#main').append(wrapperDiv);
    
});
```

```css
body
{
  padding:32px;
  background-color:#bbb;
}
.first-div
{
  color:#336;
  background-color:#9bb;
  font-size:16px;
  border: 1px solid #336;
  padding:32px;
  text-align:center;
}

.second-div
{
  color:#363;
  background-color:#9b9;
  font-size:16px;
  border: 1px solid #494;
  padding:32px;
  text-align:center;
  
}
.third-div
{
  color:#633;
  background-color:#b99;
  font-size:16px;
  border: 1px solid #633;
  padding:32px;
  text-align:center;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
<div id ="main" class="container-fluid">

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odd way to go about this, but I won't question it. I will point out, however, that you're declaring the same variable in the same scope three times.

Here should be what you're looking for. Notice I've chained the wrap command, and taken out the 'find' command for it. I've also appended the elements before calling them to be wrapped:

```
var wrapWithBootstrap = function(toBeWrapped) {
  toBeWrapped.wrap('<div class="row"></div>').wrap('<div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4"></div>');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var wrapperDiv=$('<div class="first-div">    This is my first div.</div>');
  $('#main').append(wrapperDiv);
  wrapWithBootstrap(wrapperDiv);

  var wrapperDiv=$('<div class="second-div">    This is my first div.</div>');
  $('#main').append(wrapperDiv);
  wrapWithBootstrap(wrapperDiv);

  var wrapperDiv=$('<div class="third-div">    This is my first div.</div>');
  $('#main').append(wrapperDiv);
  wrapWithBootstrap(wrapperDiv);
});
```

And the codepen: http://codepen.io/shigidaMark/pen/xExQRL

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it for you http://codepen.io/dirtysmith/pen/ZpEmYW

```
function(toBeWrapped);

$(document).ready(function()
{
    var wrapperDiv=$('<div class="first-div col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">    This is my first div.</div>');
  wrapWithBootstrap(wrapperDiv);
  $('#main').append(wrapperDiv);

   var wrapperDiv=$('<div class="second-div col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">    This is my first div.</div>');
  wrapWithBootstrap(wrapperDiv);
  $('#main').append(wrapperDiv);

   var wrapperDiv=$('<div class="third-div col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">    This is my first div.</div>');
  wrapWithBootstrap(wrapperDiv);
  $('#main').append(wrapperDiv);

});
```

Comment: That solves it for just showing it right, though, I need the bootstrap wrapping to be done inside the function, actually for more complicated and conditioned wrapping.